# JS not working in PHP (document.getElementById)

Tags: javascript, php, dom, document

i'm doing a very rookie password signup thing for my web development project and i'm stuck here

```
<script>   
    <?php  
        if ( isset($_POST['enter']) ){
            if ($_POST['password']=='0000'){
                echo('document.getElementById("adminsection").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("passsection").style.display = "none" ;');
            }
            else{
                echo ("alert('password incorrect');");
            }
        }
    ?>
</script>
```

for some reason this part doesn't seem to work when the condition is met:

```
 echo('document.getElementById("adminsection").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("passsection").style.display = "none" ;');
```

adminsection and passsection are just section tags that contain the elemnts of the page and they look kinda like this

```
<form style="width:100%; margin:10% 0 10% 0" action="administrator123.php" method="POST">
<section id="passsection">
    <input style="margin-left:-5px" id="passfield" name="password" type="password" placeholder="****">
    <input type="submit" id="password" name="enter" value="enter">
</section>
<section id="adminsection">
    <p>hey</p>
</section>
</form>
```

the goal behind this code is to hide the passsection and show the adminsection upon entering the correct password
i'd appreciate it very much if you provided me with a solution that doesn't involve jQuery

Comment: Hi, I'd love to help, can you please run your code, open your inspector tools, and paste in the. generated DOM output for this section?

Comment: Where is the script tag in the HTML? These elements may not exist at the time the script runs. Maybe try putting the script tag at the bottom of the document or put the script content in some kind of load event handler e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event#basic_usage

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing javascript and PHP the wrong way.

**Normal form submission.** The order of operations are:

- you have a form in html (you're missing the form element)
- user submits the form
- this sends the submit to the server causing a page load/reload
- server-side PHP checks if the password is good
- The newly loaded page does stuff with the PHP output.

```html
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['enter']) ){
    if ($_POST['password']=='0000'){
       $loggedin = true;
    } else {
       $error="Password was incorrect";
    }
}
?>

  <?php if (!$loggedin) {?>
  <section id="passsection">

    <?php if ($error) {?>
    <div class='error'>
      <?php echo $error;?> </div>
    <?}?>

      <form method='post'>
        <input style="margin-left:-5px" id="passfield" name="password" type="password" placeholder="****">
        <input type="submit" id="password" name="enter" value="enter">
      </form>
  </section>

  <?}?>
```

**Ajax form submission.** The order of operations are:

- you have a form in html (you're missing the form element)
- user submits the form
- javascript prevents the form from reloading the page, and sends the form data through ajax to the server
- server-side PHP checks if the password is good and outputs the response in json_encode() format
- ajax function gets response and uses that data to provide feedback.

Your php will live in a separate file

**doLogin.php**

```
<?php
$loggedin = false;
if ( isset($_POST['enter']) ){
    if ($_POST['password']=='0000'){
       $loggedin = true;
    } else {
       $error="Password was incorrect";
    }
}

$response = array('isLoggedIn' => $loggedin);
if ($error) $response['error'] = $error;
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

```js
document.querySelector('#passsection form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the page from reloading
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let url = "/php/doLogin.php";
  request.open("POST", url, true);
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
      var jsonData = JSON.parse(request.response);
      if (jsonData.isLoggedIn) {
        document.querySelector('#passsection').style.display = "none"
      } else if (jsonData.error) {
        document.querySelector('#passsection form .error').innerHTML = jsonData.error
      }
    }
  };
  let data = JSON.stringify({
    "passfield": document.getElementById("passfield").value
    });
  request.send(data);
});
```

```html
<section id="passsection">
  <div class='error'></div>
  <form method='post'>
    <input style="margin-left:-5px" id="passfield" name="password" type="password" placeholder="****">
    <input type="submit" id="password" name="enter" value="enter">
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: in the original code i had the form tag with method="POST" and action="#" , sorry forgot to include it up top i'll edit the question

Comment: ok,  updated my answer. form submission 2 ways. Hope this helps illuminate.